# Why when I put $F=[0,1,2z]$ in terms of $r(t)=(\cos(t) , \sin(t) , t^2 )$ is the answer $0,1,2t^2?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I don't understand how the $y$ term becomes $1.$ I assumed it would become $\sin(t)$
$$F=[0,1,2z]. . . . . .  r(t)=[\cos(t),\sin(t),t^2], $$
so I thought $$F(r(t))=[0,\sin(t),2t^2].$$
But no, it's apparently $$F(r(t))=[0,1,2t^2].$$
Can you explain why I'm wrong here?

Comment: Well, if it explicitly says that $F=[\dots,1,\dots]$, how can you ever get something else than $1$ in that middle position?

Comment: Check again your data, at the moment it very unclear. It could be simply a typo for F=[0,y,2z].

Comment: What question is $(0,1,2t^2)$ the answer to?

Comment: F is a vector field, r(t) is the path a particle takes. it was a question about the work done. and no its not a typo. i think the first person was right im just an idiot.

so if it was [y,0,2z] in terms of r(t)=[0,1,2t] it would be [1,0,2t^2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition

$$F (x,y,z)=(0,1,2z) $$

thus

$$F (\cos (t),\sin (t),t^2)=(0,1,2t^2) $$